# Calculated column based off values in another column in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I just started using Spotfire and am having a bit of a tough time figuring out how to create a particular calculated column.  I'm pretty sure I need to use the OVER function, but I haven't quite figured it out and there's almost no documentation or examples on the interwebs.

Here's a sample of the data I'm working with:

```
loc     wafer   x   y   pass    bin  
T25     10      2   37  1       13  
T25     10      2   37  2       6  
CMI     10      2   37  NA      13  
T25     10      2   37  NA      13  
T25     10      2   38  1       13  
T25     10      2   38  2       13  
CMI     10      2   38  NA      13  
T25     10      2   38  NA      13  
T25     10      2   70  1       1  
T25     10      2   70  2       4  
CMI     10      2   70  NA      1  
CMI     10      2   70  NA      1  
T25     10      2   70  NA      1  
T25     10      2   70  NA      1
```

The column I'm trying to create will be based off of the pass value.  So, for each location, wafer, and x-y coordinate, whenever pass=1, I want to copy the bin value into the new column for that row.  I also want that same pass=1 bin value to be copied into the matching location, wafer, x-y coordinate where pass is not NA.  Here's what I would like to see:

```
loc     wafer   x   y   pass    bin newCol  
T25     10      2   37  1       13  13  
T25     10      2   37  2       6   13  
CMI     10      2   37  NA      13  NA  
T25     10      2   37  NA      13  NA  
T25     10      2   38  1       13  13  
T25     10      2   38  2       13  13  
CMI     10      2   38  NA      13  NA  
T25     10      2   38  NA      13  NA  
T25     10      2   70  1       1   1  
T25     10      2   70  2       4   1  
CMI     10      2   70  NA      1   NA  
CMI     10      2   70  NA      1   NA  
T25     10      2   70  NA      1   NA  
T25     10      2   70  NA      1   NA
```

My current expression is as follows:

```
CASE
  WHEN [pass] = "1" THEN Concatenate([bin]) OVER ([location],[wafer],[x],[y])
END
```

It copies the bin to any rows with pass=1, but not the the pass=2 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** to avoid having the `[bin]` value when `[pass] = "NA"`, surround the whole thing in an `If()` like so:

```
If([pass]!="NA", First(If([pass]="1",String([bin]),"NA")) OVER (Intersect([loc],[wafer],[x],[y])), "NA")
```

---

I think you're on the right track, but this isn't really a simple expression! here's what I came up with:

```
First(If([pass]="1",String([bin]),"NA")) OVER (Intersect([loc],[wafer],[x],[y]))
```

so let's break this down:

- `First(...)` is chosen because we want, well, the first result! the inline `If()` will return an **NA** for each row in which `[pass] != 1`, and you can observe this by changing `First()` to `Concatenate()`
- `If([pass] = "1", String([bin]), "NA")` makes sure that we *only* ever record the value in `[bin]` or **NA**. without this, our result would contain all values for `[bin]` -- try removing the `If()` and see!
- `OVER Intersect([loc], [wafer], [x], [y])` creates a hierarchy of "nodes" (see documentation linked below) for each unique combination of these four columns.

**NOTE** that depending on the size of your data, this might be a very slow expression, due to the `Intersect(...)`. if you find that it takes a long time to calculate when the data is refreshed, you may have better results with two columns:

1. `[ID]` which is simply `Concatenate([loc], [wafer], [x], [y])`
2. `[Result]` which is the above answer, except the end looks like `... OVER [ID]` (we don't need to use `Intersect()` since we are only comparing across a single column)

---

for documentation on the OVER functions with examples, check the Spotfire help file at [Advanced Custom Expressions](http://stn.spotfire.com/spotfire_client_help/ncfe/ncfe_advanced_custom_expressions.htm). I know it's still not perfectly understandable; OVER functions are a bit of a stretch for the brain :)

---

just to add some context to your first attempt and why it wasn't working:

since you aren't doing any calculation on the value for `[bin]`, you simplify by using the following case:

```
WHEN [pass] = "1" THEN [bin]
```

of course the expression that you have is not returning any value when `[pass] != "1"`, as you haven't specified any other cases. to fix that, you'd need something like this:

```
CASE
  WHEN [pass] = "1" THEN [bin]
  WHEN [pass] != "NA" THEN ...
  ELSE null
END
```

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers.  This has been very helpful!  So, when I run this, it's adding the bin value to the rows with no pass value in them.  How can I get it to ignore the rows that do not have a pass value?  So for example it's coming out like:

loc     wafer   x   y   pass    bin newCol  
T25     10      2   37  1       13  13  
T25     10      2   37  2       6   13  
CMI     10      2   37  NA      13  NA  
T25     10      2   37  NA      13  13

Comment: I didn't realize that would come out looking strange.  Basically, the newCol value for the 4th row (not including the header), is coming out to 13 instead of NA.

Comment: gotcha! I updated the answer to reflect that requirement :)

Comment: Fantastic.  You have been a great help!  Thanks again!

Comment: @BrittanyEnfield great, glad I could help :) would you mind marking the question as solved?